# Is it possible to merge 3 videos with ffmpeg by -f concat and crossfade without video content

Tags: filter, ffmpeg, concatenation

I want to merge 3 .mov files quickly without losing any resolution. I want to be able to distinguish the 3 pieces of videos after merge.

```
"ffmpeg -f concat" does not lose resolution and quick without crossfade.
```

But, I can't distinguish 3 videos.

As far as I know ffmpeg filter can be used add crossfade, but it have to use video start/end content to do the merger, which might involve transcoding. It won't be fast compared with 'concat', which won't do transcoding, but simply copying.

Here is the content (ffmpeg -i video.mov) of one of 3 videos:

```
ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --enable-avresample --cc=clang --host-cflags='-I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include -I/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-12.jdk/Contents/Home/include/darwin' --host-ldflags= --enable-ffplay --enable-gnutls --enable-gpl --enable-libaom --enable-libbluray --enable-libmp3lame --enable-libopus --enable-librubberband --enable-libsnappy --enable-libtesseract --enable-libtheora --enable-libvorbis --enable-libvpx --enable-libx264 --enable-libx265 --enable-libxvid --enable-lzma --enable-libfontconfig --enable-libfreetype --enable-frei0r --enable-libass --enable-libopencore-amrnb --enable-libopencore-amrwb --enable-libopenjpeg --enable-librtmp --enable-libspeex --enable-videotoolbox --disable-libjack --disable-indev=jack --enable-libaom --enable-libsoxr
  libavutil      56. 22.100 / 56. 22.100
  libavcodec     58. 35.100 / 58. 35.100
  libavformat    58. 20.100 / 58. 20.100
  libavdevice    58.  5.100 / 58.  5.100
  libavfilter     7. 40.101 /  7. 40.101
  libavresample   4.  0.  0 /  4.  0.  0
  libswscale      5.  3.100 /  5.  3.100
  libswresample   3.  3.100 /  3.  3.100
  libpostproc    55.  3.100 / 55.  3.100
Input #0, mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2, from '..../(edited)/VMEK8375.MOV':
  Metadata:
    major_brand     : qt  
    minor_version   : 0
    compatible_brands: qt  
    creation_time   : 2019-06-30T01:28:04.000000Z
    com.apple.quicktime.model: iPhone
    com.apple.quicktime.software: ZHIYUN
    com.apple.quicktime.creationdate: 2019-06-30T09:28:04Z
  Duration: 00:00:07.61, start: 0.000000, bitrate: 4386 kb/s
    Stream #0:0(und): Video: hevc (Main) (hvc1 / 0x31637668), yuv420p(tv, smpte170m/bt709/bt709), 1280x720, 4329 kb/s, 30.01 fps, 30 tbr, 600 tbn, 600 tbc (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-30T01:28:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Video
      encoder         : HEVC
    Stream #0:1(und): Audio: aac (LC) (mp4a / 0x6134706D), 44100 Hz, mono, fltp, 94 kb/s (default)
    Metadata:
      creation_time   : 2019-06-30T01:28:04.000000Z
      handler_name    : Core Media Audio
```

If I don't care about crossfade with video content, just some 'nice' black screen in between (It would be nice I add some text, like date + time on the black screen) is good enough for me. Is it possible to do 'concat' and simple crossfade without video 'content'?

Comment: Thank you for response. What 3 videos file info you want?

Comment: Too long. This is partial of 1 mov file. ffmpeg version 4.1.3 Copyright (c) 2000-2019 the FFmpeg developers
  built with Apple LLVM version 10.0.1 (clang-1001.0.46.3)
  configuration: --prefix=/usr/local/Cellar/ffmpeg/4.1.3 --enable-shared --enable-pthreads --enable-version3 --enable-hardcoded-tables --

Comment: You can [edit] your question to add the requested info. Comments are too limited.

Comment: OK. I added it.

Comment: The output is missing the info from the other two inputs.

Comment: I know. 2 other files are the same iphone recorded. I don't see the point to list it.

Comment: Ok. I had to ensure that they had the same attributes. Many users want to concatenate arbitrary videos that do not have same attributes, but that is not possible without filtering/re-encoding.

Answer (score 0):

Filtering requires re-encoding, so fading is not an option. Instead you can make videos that go between the main content.

Create middle videos. Ensure that you match the attributes of the main videos:

```
ffmpeg -y -f lavfi -i color=c=black:s=1280x720:r=30 -f lavfi -i anullsrc=channel_layout=mono:sample_rate=44100 -vf "drawtext=text='your text':fontsize=24:fontcolor=white:x=(w-text_w)/2:y=(h-text_h)/2" -c:v libx265 -profile:v main -c:a aac -tag:v hvc1 -t 5 -video_track_timescale 600 black1.mov
```

Make `input.txt`:

```
file '1.mov'
file 'black1.mov'
file '2.mov'
file 'black2.mov'
file '3.mov'
```

Then use concat demuxer:

```
ffmpeg -f concat -i input.txt -c copy output.mov
```

Comment: Great!!! I tried. black1.mov is created successfully, text shows. I tried to merge with your recommended command: 1.mov, black1.mov, 2.mov. I saw 1st movie (seems becomes short), then, the video becomes noise, no black1.mov, no 2.mov. Strange, the merge is super fast. After remove: black1.mov, and do same merge, I saw: 1.mov, 2.mov.

Comment: @user3792705 Provide a link to the input files.